# Why would adding MySQL code to an epoll based web crawler slow it down so much?

Tags: mysql, c, curl, epoll

I have a working code which uses libcurl and epoll to crawl websites:

https://github.com/JamesRead5737/libcurlmemoryleak/blob/master/crawler.c

Typical output is:

```
Parsed sites: 0, 1024 parallel connections, 10989 still running, 10989 transfers    Exiting normally.
Parsed sites: 0, 0 parallel connections, 0 still running, 0 transfersrsrFinished all in progress downloads.
Exiting.
```

As you can see the code hits the hard coded limit of 1024 parallel connections. This consumes up to 3 Gbps on my dedicated server.

Adding Mysql code like so:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <mysql.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define MSG_OUT stdout
#define DEFAULT_QUEUE_LENGTH 10000
#define mycase(code) \
        case code: s = __STRING(code)

#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 1024

MYSQL *mysql_con;

/* Global information, common to all connections */
typedef struct _GlobalInfo
{
    int epfd;    /* epoll filedescriptor */
    int tfd;     /* timer filedescriptor */
    CURLM *multi;
    int still_running;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int concurrent_connections;
    pthread_mutex_t parsed_lock;
    int parsed_sites;
    int transfers;
} GlobalInfo;

int new_body_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g);

/* Information associated with a specific easy handle */
typedef struct _ConnInfo
{
    CURL *easy;
    char *url;
    GlobalInfo *global;
    char error[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    size_t size;
    char *data;
} ConnInfo;

/* Information associated with a specific socket */
typedef struct _SockInfo
{
    curl_socket_t sockfd;
    CURL *easy;
    int action;
    long timeout;
    GlobalInfo *global;
} SockInfo;

void
mysql_stop()
{
    mysql_close(mysql_con);
}

void
mysql_start()
{
    mysql_con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (mysql_con == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_real_connect(mysql_con, "localhost", "crawler", "password", "crawl", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frontier` (`url` varchar(2084) NOT NULL, `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`), KEY `url_2` (`url`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
        mysql_stop();
                exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crawled` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `url` varchar(2084) DEFAULT NULL, `title` varchar(768) DEFAULT NULL, `date` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL, `last_modified` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL, `links` int DEFAULT NULL, `backlinks` int DEFAULT NULL, `http_code` int DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`), KEY `http_code` (`http_code`), KEY `title` (`title`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                mysql_stop();
                exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emails` (`email` varchar(2084) NOT NULL, `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`), KEY `email_2` (`email`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=737 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                mysql_stop();
                exit(1);
    }
}

void
mysql_url_visited_push(char *url, char *title)
{
    char sql[8192];
    char escaped_url[(strlen(url)*2)+1];
    if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_url, url, strlen(url)))
    {
    }
    if (title != NULL)
    {
        char escaped_title[(strlen(title)*2)+1];
        if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_title, title, strlen(title)))
        {
        }
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO crawled (url, title) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", escaped_url, escaped_title);
    } else {
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO crawled (url, title) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", escaped_url, title);
    }
    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, sql))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_visited_push sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
    }
}

int
mysql_url_visited_find(char *url)
{
    char sql[8192];
    char escaped_url[(strlen(url)*2)+1];
    if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_url, url, strlen(url)))
    {
    }
    sprintf(sql, "SELECT * FROM crawled WHERE url = '%s'", escaped_url);
    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, sql))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_visited_find sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
    } else {
        MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysql_con);
        if (!result)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
        } else if (result > 0){
            mysql_free_result(result);
            return 1;
        } else if (result == 0) {
            mysql_free_result(result);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int
mysql_url_frontier_find(char *url)
{
    char sql[8192];
    char escaped_url[(strlen(url)*2)+1];
    if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_url, url, strlen(url)))
    {
    }
        sprintf(sql, "SELECT * FROM frontier WHERE url = '%s'", escaped_url);
        if (mysql_query(mysql_con, sql))
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_frontier_find sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
        } else {
                MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysql_con);      
                if (!result)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysql_con));
                } else if (result > 0){
            mysql_free_result(result);
                        return 1;
                } else if (result == 0) {
            mysql_free_result(result);
                        return 0;
                }
        }
}

void 
mysql_url_frontier_push(char *url)
{
    char sql[8192];
    char escaped_url[(strlen(url)*2)+1];
    if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_url, url, strlen(url)))
    {
    }
        sprintf(sql, "INSERT IGNORE INTO frontier (url) VALUES ('%s')", escaped_url);
        if (mysql_query(mysql_con, sql))
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_frontier_push sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
        }
}

char *
mysql_url_frontier_pop()
{
    char *url = NULL;
    char sql[8192];
    if (mysql_query(mysql_con, "SELECT url FROM frontier ORDER BY id") == 0)
    {
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysql_con);
        if (result == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_frontier_pop mysql_store_result sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
        {
            url = strdup(row[0]);
            char escaped_url[(strlen(url)*2)+1];
            if (!mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_con, escaped_url, url, strlen(url)))
            {
            }
            sprintf( sql, "DELETE FROM frontier WHERE url = '%s'", escaped_url);
            if (mysql_query(mysql_con, sql))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "mysql_url_frontier_pop mysql_query sql=%s %s\n", sql, mysql_error(mysql_con));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        mysql_free_result(result);
    }
    return url;
}

int
starts_with(const char *str, const char *pre)
{
        size_t lenstr;
        size_t lenpre;

        if (str == NULL || pre == NULL)
                return (-1);

        lenstr = strlen(str);
        lenpre = strlen(pre);

        if (lenstr < lenpre)
                return (-1);

    return (memcmp(pre, str, lenpre));
}

char *
url_sanitize(char *base_url, char *url, int size)
{
        char *newurl;
        int base_url_len = strlen(base_url);

        if (starts_with(url, "http") == 0) {
                newurl = malloc(size+1);
                if (newurl == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "1 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                        exit(1);
                }

                strncpy(newurl, url, size);
                newurl[size] = '\0';

        } else {
                if (starts_with(url, "//") == 0) {
                        newurl = malloc(size+7);
                        if (newurl == NULL) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "2 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        strncpy(newurl, "https:", 6);
                        strncpy(newurl+6, url, size);
                        newurl[size+6] = '\0';
                } else {
                        newurl = malloc(base_url_len + size + 2);
                        if (newurl == NULL) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "3 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        strncpy(newurl, base_url, base_url_len);
                        strncpy(newurl + base_url_len, url, size);
                        newurl[size + base_url_len] = '\0';
                }
        }

        return (newurl);
}

char *
html_title_find(char *html)
{
        char *newurl, *first, *last;
        int size = 0;

        first = strstr(html, "<title>");
        if (first == NULL)
                return (NULL);

        first += strlen("<title>");

        last = strstr(first, "</title>");
        if (last == NULL)
                return (NULL);

        size = last - first;

        newurl = malloc(size+1);
        if (newurl == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "4 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                exit(1);
        }

        strncpy(newurl, first, size);
        newurl[size] = '\0';

        return (newurl);
}

void
html_link_find(char *url, char *html)
{
        char *first, *last, *newurl;
        int size = 0;

        first = html;

        while (first && last) {
                        first = strstr(first, "href=\"");
                        if (first == NULL)
                                continue;

                        first += strlen("href=\"");

                        last = strchr(first, '\"');
                        if (last == NULL)
                                continue;

                        size = last - first;

                        newurl = url_sanitize(url, first, size);

                        if (strstr(newurl, "mailto")) {
                                free(newurl);
                                continue;
                        } else {
                if (mysql_url_visited_find(newurl) && mysql_url_frontier_find(newurl)) {
                    mysql_url_frontier_push(newurl);
                }
                free(newurl);
            }

        }
}

void
parsed_sites_inc(GlobalInfo *g)
{
        g->parsed_sites++;
}

void
html_parse(char *url, char *html)
{
    char *title;

    title = html_title_find(html);
    html_link_find(url, html);
    mysql_url_visited_push(url, title);

    free(title);
}

/* Die if we get a bad CURLMcode somewhere */ 
static void
mcode_or_die(const char *where, CURLMcode code)
{
    if (CURLM_OK != code) {
        const char *s;

        switch (code) {
            mycase(CURLM_BAD_HANDLE); break;
            mycase(CURLM_BAD_EASY_HANDLE); break;
            mycase(CURLM_OUT_OF_MEMORY); break;
            mycase(CURLM_INTERNAL_ERROR); break;
            mycase(CURLM_UNKNOWN_OPTION); break;
            mycase(CURLM_LAST); break;
            default: s = "CURLM_unknown"; break;
            mycase(CURLM_BAD_SOCKET);
            fprintf(MSG_OUT, "ERROR: %s returns %s\n", where, s);
            /* ignore this error */ 
            return;
        }

        fprintf(MSG_OUT, "ERROR: %s returns %s\n", where, s);
        exit(code);
    }
}

void
print_progress(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    printf("\rParsed sites: %d, %d parallel connections, %d still running, %d transfers\t", 
            g->parsed_sites, g->concurrent_connections, g->still_running, g->transfers);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void
transfers_inc(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    g->transfers++;

    print_progress(g);
}

void
transfers_dec(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    g->transfers--;

    print_progress(g);
}

void
concurrent_connections_inc(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    g->concurrent_connections++;

    print_progress(g);
}

void
concurrent_connections_dec(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    g->concurrent_connections--;

    print_progress(g);
}

static void timer_cb(GlobalInfo* g, int revents);

/* Update the timer after curl_multi library does it's thing. Curl will
 * inform us through this callback what it wants the new timeout to be,
 * after it does some work. */ 
static int
multi_timer_cb(CURLM *multi, long timeout_ms, GlobalInfo *g)
{
    struct itimerspec its;

    //fprintf(MSG_OUT, "multi_timer_cb: Setting timeout to %ld ms\n", timeout_ms);

    if (timeout_ms > 0) {
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
        its.it_value.tv_sec = timeout_ms / 1000;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = (timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000 * 1000;
    } else if(timeout_ms == 0) {
        /* libcurl wants us to timeout now, however setting both fields of
         * new_value.it_value to zero disarms the timer. The closest we can
         * do is to schedule the timer to fire in 1 ns. */ 
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
        its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;
    } else {
        memset(&its, 0, sizeof(struct itimerspec));
    }

    timerfd_settime(g->tfd, /*flags=*/ 0, &its, NULL);

    return (0);
}

/* Check for completed transfers, and remove their easy handles */ 
static void
check_multi_info(GlobalInfo *g)
{
    char *eff_url;
    CURLMsg *msg;
    int msgs_left;
    ConnInfo *conn;
    CURL *easy;
    char *ct;
    double time;
    double dl;
    long header_size;
    long response_code;
    //CURLcode res;

    while ((msg = curl_multi_info_read(g->multi, &msgs_left))) {
        if (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) {
            easy = msg->easy_handle;
            //res = msg->data.result;
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &conn);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &eff_url);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &time);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD, &dl);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
            curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE, &header_size);

            if (response_code == 200 && dl == 0.0 && (starts_with(ct, "text/html") || starts_with(ct, "text/plain")))
            {
                /* This should be a response to our HEAD request */
                //printf("200 %s header size: %ld download size: %f", eff_url, header_size, dl);
                new_body_conn(eff_url, g);

            } else if (response_code == 200 && dl > 0.0 && (starts_with(ct, "text/html") || starts_with(ct, "text/plain"))){
                /* This should be a response to our GET request */
                //printf("%ld %s download size: %f content type: %s\n", response_code, eff_url, dl, ct);
                html_parse(eff_url, conn->data);
                parsed_sites_inc(g);
            }
            //fprintf(MSG_OUT, "DONE: %s => (%d) %s\n", eff_url, res, conn->error);

            curl_multi_remove_handle(g->multi, easy);
            //free(conn->url);
            free(conn->data);
            curl_easy_cleanup(easy);
            transfers_dec(g);
            free(conn);
        }
    }
}

/* Called by libevent when we get action on a multi socket filedescriptor*/ 
static void
event_cb(GlobalInfo *g, int fd, int revents)
{
    CURLMcode rc;
    struct itimerspec its;

    int action = ((revents & EPOLLIN) ? CURL_CSELECT_IN : 0) |
                 ((revents & EPOLLOUT) ? CURL_CSELECT_OUT : 0);

    rc = curl_multi_socket_action(g->multi, fd, action, &g->still_running);
    mcode_or_die("event_cb: curl_multi_socket_action", rc);

    check_multi_info(g);

    if (g->still_running <= 0) {
        //fprintf(MSG_OUT, "last transfer done, kill timeout\n");
        memset(&its, 0, sizeof(struct itimerspec));
        timerfd_settime(g->tfd, 0, &its, NULL);
    }
}

/* Called by main loop when our timeout expires */ 
static void
timer_cb(GlobalInfo* g, int revents)
{
    CURLMcode rc;
    uint64_t count = 0;
    ssize_t err = 0;

    err = read(g->tfd, &count, sizeof(uint64_t));
    if (err == -1) {
        /* Note that we may call the timer callback even if the timerfd isn't
         * readable. It's possible that there are multiple events stored in the
         * epoll buffer (i.e. the timer may have fired multiple times). The
         * event count is cleared after the first call so future events in the
         * epoll buffer will fail to read from the timer. */ 
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            //fprintf(MSG_OUT, "EAGAIN on tfd %d\n", g->tfd);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (err != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read(tfd) == %ld", err);
        perror("read(tfd)");
    }

    rc = curl_multi_socket_action(g->multi, CURL_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 0, &g->still_running);
    mcode_or_die("timer_cb: curl_multi_socket_action", rc);
    check_multi_info(g);
}

/* Assign information to a SockInfo structure */ 
static void
setsock(SockInfo *f, curl_socket_t s, CURL *e, int act, GlobalInfo *g)
{
    struct epoll_event ev;
    int kind = ((act & CURL_POLL_IN) ? EPOLLIN : 0) |
               ((act & CURL_POLL_OUT) ? EPOLLOUT : 0);

    if (f->sockfd) {
        concurrent_connections_dec(g);
        if (epoll_ctl(g->epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, f->sockfd, NULL))
            fprintf(stderr, "EPOLL_CTL_DEL failed for fd: %d : %s\n",
              f->sockfd, strerror(errno));
    }

    f->sockfd = s;
    f->action = act;
    f->easy = e;

    ev.events = kind;
    ev.data.fd = s;

    concurrent_connections_inc(g);
    if (epoll_ctl(g->epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, s, &ev)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EPOLL_CTL_ADD failed for fd: %d : %s\n",
          s, strerror(errno));
    }
}

/* Initialize a new SockInfo structure */ 
static void
addsock(curl_socket_t s, CURL *easy, int action, GlobalInfo *g)
{
    SockInfo *fdp = (SockInfo *)calloc(sizeof(SockInfo), 1);

    fdp->global = g;
    setsock(fdp, s, easy, action, g);
    curl_multi_assign(g->multi, s, fdp);
}

static size_t
write_cb(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *p)
{
    ConnInfo *conn = (ConnInfo *)p;
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

    conn->data = realloc(conn->data, conn->size + realsize + 1);
    if (conn->data == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */ 
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(conn->data[conn->size]), contents, realsize);
    conn->size += realsize;
    conn->data[conn->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

/* Create a new easy handle, and add it to the global curl_multi */ 
int
new_head_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g)
{
    ConnInfo *conn;
    CURLMcode rc;

    conn = (ConnInfo*)calloc(1, sizeof(ConnInfo));
    conn->error[0]='\0';
    conn->global = g;

    conn->easy = curl_easy_init();
    if (!conn->easy) {
        fprintf(MSG_OUT, "curl_easy_init() failed, exiting!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    transfers_inc(g);

    conn->global = g;
    conn->url = url;
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_URL, conn->url);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, conn);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, conn->error);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, conn);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, conn);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 3L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 100L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10L);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA, g);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);

    rc = curl_multi_add_handle(g->multi, conn->easy);
    mcode_or_die("new_conn: curl_multi_add_handle", rc);

    /* note that the add_handle() will set a time-out to trigger very soon so
     that the necessary socket_action() call will be called by this app */ 

    return (0);
}

/* Create a new easy handle, and add it to the global curl_multi */
int
new_body_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g)
{
        ConnInfo *conn;
        CURLMcode rc;

        conn = (ConnInfo*)calloc(1, sizeof(ConnInfo));
        conn->error[0]='\0';
        conn->global = g;

        conn->easy = curl_easy_init();
        if (!conn->easy) {
                fprintf(MSG_OUT, "curl_easy_init() failed, exiting!\n");
                exit(2);
        }
        transfers_inc(g);

        conn->global = g;
        conn->url = url;
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_URL, conn->url);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, conn);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, conn->error);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, conn);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, conn);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 3L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 100L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10L);
        curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA, g);

        rc = curl_multi_add_handle(g->multi, conn->easy);
        mcode_or_die("new_conn: curl_multi_add_handle", rc);

        /* note that the add_handle() will set a time-out to trigger very soon so
     that the necessary socket_action() call will be called by this app */

        return (0);
}

/* Clean up the SockInfo structure */ 
static void
remsock(SockInfo *f, GlobalInfo* g)
{
    if (f) {
        if (f->sockfd) {
            concurrent_connections_dec(g);
            if (epoll_ctl(g->epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, f->sockfd, NULL))
                fprintf(stderr, "EPOLL_CTL_DEL failed for fd: %d : %s\n",
                  f->sockfd, strerror(errno));
        }

        free(f);
    }
}

/* CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION */ 
static int
sock_cb(CURL *e, curl_socket_t s, int what, void *cbp, void *sockp)
{
    GlobalInfo *g = (GlobalInfo*) cbp;
    SockInfo *fdp = (SockInfo*) sockp;

    if (what == CURL_POLL_REMOVE) {
        remsock(fdp, g);
    } else {
        if (g->concurrent_connections < MAX_CONNECTIONS){
            if (!fdp) {
                addsock(s, e, what, g);
            } else {
                setsock(fdp, s, e, what, g);
            }
        }
    }

    return (0);
}

/* CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION */
static int
end_sock_cb(CURL *e, curl_socket_t s, int what, void *cbp, void *sockp)
{
        GlobalInfo *g = (GlobalInfo*) cbp;
        SockInfo *fdp = (SockInfo*) sockp;

        if (what == CURL_POLL_REMOVE) {
                remsock(fdp, g);
        }

        return (0);
}


int should_exit = 0;

void
signal_handler(int signo)
{
    should_exit = 1;
}

void *
crawler_init()
{
    GlobalInfo g;
    struct itimerspec its;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    struct epoll_event events[10000];


    memset(&g, 0, sizeof(GlobalInfo));

    g.transfers = 0;
    g.parsed_sites = 0;

    g.epfd = epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC);
    if (g.epfd == -1) {
        perror("epoll_create1 failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    g.tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_NONBLOCK | TFD_CLOEXEC);
    if (g.tfd == -1) {
        perror("timerfd_create failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&its, 0, sizeof(struct itimerspec));
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    timerfd_settime(g.tfd, 0, &its, NULL);

    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = g.tfd;
    epoll_ctl(g.epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, g.tfd, &ev);

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    g.multi = curl_multi_init();

    /* setup the generic multi interface options we want */ 
    curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, sock_cb);
    curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA, &g);
    curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, multi_timer_cb);
    curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA, &g);

    /* we don't call any curl_multi_socket*() function yet as we have no handles added! */ 

    //printf("Starting crawler...\n");

    while (!should_exit) {
        int idx;
        int err = epoll_wait(g.epfd, events, sizeof(events)/sizeof(struct epoll_event), 10000);
        char *url;

        url = mysql_url_frontier_pop();

        new_head_conn(url, &g);

        if (err == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                fprintf(MSG_OUT, "note: wait interrupted\n");
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("epoll_wait");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        for (idx = 0; idx < err; ++idx) {
            if (events[idx].data.fd == g.tfd) {
                timer_cb(&g, events[idx].events);
            } else {
                event_cb(&g, events[idx].data.fd, events[idx].events);
            }
        }
    }

    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "Exiting normally.\n");
    fflush(MSG_OUT);

    curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, end_sock_cb);
    while (g.concurrent_connections > 0 || g.transfers > 0)
    {
        int idx;
                int err = epoll_wait(g.epfd, events, sizeof(events)/sizeof(struct epoll_event), 10000);

                if (err == -1) {
                        if (errno == EINTR) {
                                fprintf(MSG_OUT, "note: wait interrupted\n");
                                continue;
                        } else {
                                perror("epoll_wait");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                }

                for (idx = 0; idx < err; ++idx) {
                        if (events[idx].data.fd == g.tfd) {
                                timer_cb(&g, events[idx].events);
                        } else {
                                event_cb(&g, events[idx].data.fd, events[idx].events);
                        }
                }

    }

    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "Finished all in progress downloads.\n");
    fflush(MSG_OUT);

    curl_multi_cleanup(g.multi);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return (NULL);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int cleanup = 0, opt, ret;

    should_exit = 0;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGKILL, signal_handler);

    mysql_start();
    crawler_init();
    mysql_stop();


    printf("Exiting.\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Typical output is:

```
Parsed sites: 42, 6 parallel connections, 4 still running, 6 transfersssExiting normally.
Parsed sites: 48, 0 parallel connections, 0 still running, 0 transfers  Finished all in progress downloads.
Exiting.
```

As you can see the app doesn't hit the hard coded number of max parallel connections. Not even close. Moreover it consumes about 3 Mbps bandwidth only.

Why? I don't understand why just adding MySQL code would cause the program to not be able to run to its full potential. To not be able to hit the hard coded number of max parallel connections.

Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

**EDIT**

Here is some gprof output:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 44.49      0.04     0.04    12668     0.00     0.00  mysql_url_visited_find
 33.37      0.07     0.03    12668     0.00     0.00  mysql_url_frontier_push
 11.12      0.08     0.01    12668     0.00     0.00  mysql_url_frontier_find
 11.12      0.09     0.01      100     0.10     0.90  html_link_find
  0.00      0.09     0.00    17355     0.00     0.00  starts_with
  0.00      0.09     0.00    12669     0.00     0.00  url_sanitize
  0.00      0.09     0.00     2651     0.00     0.00  mcode_or_die
  0.00      0.09     0.00     2432     0.00     0.04  check_multi_info
  0.00      0.09     0.00     2420     0.00     0.04  event_cb
  0.00      0.09     0.00     1288     0.00     0.00  print_progress
  0.00      0.09     0.00      425     0.00     0.00  concurrent_connections_dec
  0.00      0.09     0.00      425     0.00     0.00  concurrent_connections_inc
  0.00      0.09     0.00      425     0.00     0.00  setsock
  0.00      0.09     0.00      303     0.00     0.00  remsock
  0.00      0.09     0.00      299     0.00     0.00  addsock
  0.00      0.09     0.00      219     0.00     0.00  transfers_dec
  0.00      0.09     0.00      219     0.00     0.00  transfers_inc
  0.00      0.09     0.00      116     0.00     0.00  mysql_url_frontier_pop
  0.00      0.09     0.00      116     0.00     0.00  new_head_conn
  0.00      0.09     0.00      103     0.00     0.00  new_body_conn
  0.00      0.09     0.00      100     0.00     0.90  html_parse
  0.00      0.09     0.00      100     0.00     0.00  html_title_find
  0.00      0.09     0.00      100     0.00     0.00  mysql_url_visited_push
  0.00      0.09     0.00      100     0.00     0.00  parsed_sites_inc
  0.00      0.09     0.00       32     0.00     0.01  timer_cb
  0.00      0.09     0.00        1     0.00    90.09  crawler_init
  0.00      0.09     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  mysql_start
  0.00      0.09     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  mysql_stop
```

Comment: Didn't look at the (lengthy!) code, but clearly, adding a DBMS to the system might add some overhead. Then it depends upon many factors, like the configuration of MySQL and tables...

Comment: @e2-e4 What does that have to do with the number of parallel connections?

Comment: Are you able to identify which specific MySQL query is making it slow?

Comment: maybe look at using a [mysql async api](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-asynchronous-interface.html) , [bulk inserting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) and [optimizing insert statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-asynchronous-interface.html)

Comment: also when you have a unique key on a field, there is no need for an additional key on the same field.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I added some gprof output to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your mysql code is synchronous — your event loop isn't doing anything while you wait for mysql to respond to a query or acknowledge an insert, and you're spending 90% of your time in mysql-related functions. You're not getting anywhere near your concurrent connections limit because the DB bottleneck limits the rate at which you issue new HTTP requests, and all of your outstanding ones *finish* while you're waiting on the DB.

Fixing this is not simple, but some general advice:

1. Avoid talking to the DB if you can. The 'frontier' stuff looks like state that could just as well be kept in-process.
2. Use an asynchronous library to interact with the DB and integrate it into your event loop, so that you can continue with other work while DB queries are outstanding.
3. Make sure your DB has the necessary indexes, or consider using something like redis instead of mysql, where access patterns are more explicit, simple accesses are insanely fast, and you can't really "accidentally" write a badly-performing query.

Comment: @JamesRead no, it's not that simple. I've added some advice to my answer though.

Comment: I already have a redis version of the code. The in memory strategy though is impractical because the exponential growth of the frontier means it is not long before the OOM gets hungry for the kill.

Comment: can similar results be made by using threads to handle the SQL queries?